# mysqli::query() Couldn't fetch Database

Tags: php, mysqli

I have an object with a property of an instance to a [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) database connection. I'm attempting to write some data to the database on destruct of the object, as such:

```
class A {
    function __destruct()
    {
        $this->shutdown();  
    }

    function shutdown()
    {
        $this->mysqli->query("UPDATE `table` SET field='val'");
    }
....
}
```

But I keep getting the `Couldn't fetch Database` error. I assume the garbage collection is killing the db connection resource internal to the mysqli instance...?

I'm trying to determine the best way to handle this scenario. Ideally without the need to do new connections or reconnect on each destruct, due to all the database issues that'd cause.

Comment: Are you copying the mysqli object from somewhere else ? or created in the constructor or any method of this class itself ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
function __destruct()
{
    $this->shutdown();  
    parent::__destruct();
}
```

Comment: I haven't inherited any classes in this particular example, and that doesn't relate to the mysqli object losing it's connection either...